# What do I need to bring to the bank when applying for a loan?

Tags: united-states, loans, documents

What do I need to bring to the bank when applying for a loan?  Should I bring pay stubs or other evidence of financial stability?  What will help my chances of being approved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @duffbeer703 mentioned, it really depends on the type of loan. But you might not know what type of loan you will eligible for:

- unsecured versus secured?
- personal versus debt consolidation?
- line of credit versus home improvement?

You WILL know whether you are applying for boat loan versus a home mortgage though!

**What will help your chances of being approved?**

If possible, make an appointment in advance with a loan officer! That's better than just walking in. (It might increase your chances of being perceived as a responsible, valued bank customer.)

Focus on the purpose of the loan. Let the bank representative tell you what your options are. If you are told that you don't qualify, ask if there is something else that they could suggest. It might mean paying a higher rate of interest, or using some other asset or account as collateral for a secured loan. It is up to you whether you want to do that. Depends on your situation, urgency of need, trade-off's.

**Documents to bring with**

Start by looking at the bank's website. See if there are any suggestions there, for document req's. If that isn't helpful, call on the telephone. ***Say that you want to speak to a loan officer.*** Mention any accounts or other existing relationship you have with the bank. Then describe as best you can what type of loan you want, the purpose (to buy a house, boat, car, repay student loans at lower interest rate etc).

You'll need some combination of the following:

- Proof of ID which in the United States, (was in the question tag), would be a picture ID.
- A driver's license or state ID card is good. If you don't have those, then a U.S. Passport or military ID.
- Social security number (but not necessarily the card)
- Prior year's tax returns, other financial account statements (or account numbers if with the same bank)
- Pay stubs or something that shows income.

Also, when you make the appointment or call, you may be told to bring title on property, vehicle, credit card statement, student loan docs. It all depends on the type of loan.

Good luck, hope you get what you want!

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the loan. For an unsecured personal loan, you need proof of ID.

For a mortgage, you'll need 1-2 prior year tax returns, two or more recent original paystubs, identification and recent savings/brokerage account statements. The bank will let you know of their particular documentation process when you speak with the.

Comment: Sudden ending there.  Loan Officer perhaps?